# Increment global variable alternative in 2 threads using pipes in linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, variables, pipe

I want to increment a global variable alternative in two threads using pipes for sincronization. How I can do it?

Comment: You'll have to explain what you want to do better.  Using a pipe to synchronize multithreaded updates of a global variable is like using a chicken as a screwdriver - it makes no sense.

Comment: I want to know how to use pipes for communication between threads.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
void *pipeReader( void *arg )
{
    int *pipeFDs= ( int * ) arg;
    int readFD = pipeFDs[ 1 ];
    for ( ;; )
    {
        int value;
        read( readFD, &value, sizeof( value ) );
        printf( "value: %d\n", value );
    }
    return( NULL );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int pipeFDs[ 2 ];
    pthread_t tid;
    pipe( pipeFDs );
    pthread_create( &tid, NULL, pipeReader, pipeFDs );
    int ii;
    for ( ii = 1; ii < argc; ii++ )
    {
        int value = atoi( argv[ ii ] );
        write( pipeFDs[ 0 ], &value, sizeof( value ) );
        sleep( 1 );
    }
    return( 0 );
}
```

I left out the proper header files and that code does no error checking.

And you need to read this:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html